# This selected team A is different from the team B originally used to build this item

Tags: xcode

I developed an app with using my personal Apple developer account at beginning, then I was involved to another team and get this error when exporting as ad-hoc ipa file:

[image: What should I do?]

What should I do?

Comment: Sign it with the correct key, maybe?

Comment: @Abizern I signed but not working.

Comment: I just ran into this issue myself. A vendor built the app using their info. Then sent us the .xcarchive and I tried to submit the app. Got the same error. It's something I did dozens of times in Xcode 5, but now it seems to be complaining I need to build with the same team that I distribute with.

Comment: @Allen did you find any solution???

Answer (score 28, accepted):

[image]

1. Change Team name here.
2. Turn off Xcode and restart.
3. Archive.

Comment: This worked for me as well. I'm developing for a partner company and had to move an app from our Apple Developer account to theirs.  You need to make sure you have your partner's development/distribution keys set up, then pick the Team as explained in MKatleast3's solution.  I did get a "Warning: Potential loss of keychain access".

Answer (score 0):

You should request the distribution certificate by the correct team's private key. Open the keychain, select the team's private key, then use the key to request a certificate from apple.